# Uncaught TypeError: UICtrl.addListItem is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom, error-handling

I've been sitting here for a solid hour and I can't figure out what's wrong.

I'm a newbie so please don't judge.

```
var budgetController = (function() {
    var Expense = function(id, description, value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.value = value;
    };

    var Income = function(id, description, value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.value = value;
    };

    var data = {
        allItems: {
            exp: [],
            inc: []
        },
        totals: {
            exp: 0,
            inc: 0
        }
    };

    return {
        addItem: function(type, des, val) {
            var newItem, ID;

            if (data.allItems[type].length > 0) {
                ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1;
            } else {
                ID = 0;
            }

            if (type === 'exp') {
                newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val);
            } else if (type === 'inc') {
                newItem = new Income(ID, des, val);
            }

            data.allItems[type].push(newItem);
            return newItem;
        },
        addListItem: function(obj, type) {
            var html, newHTML, element;

            if (type === 'inc') {
                element = DOMstrings.incomesContainer;
                html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="income-%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
            } else if (type === 'exp') {
                element = DOMstrings.expensesContainer;
                html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="expense-%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__percentage">21%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
            }

            newHTML = html.replace('%id%', obj.id);
            newHTML = html.replace('%description%', obj.description);
            newHTML = html.replace('%value%', obj.value);

            document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHTML);
        }
    };
})();

var UIController = (function() {
    var DOMstrings = {
        inputType: '.add__type',
        inputDescription: '.add__description',
        inputValue: '.add__value',
        inputBtn: '.add__btn',
        incomesContainer: '.income__list',
        expensesContainer: '.expenses__list'
    };

    return {
        getInput: function() {
            return {
                type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value,
                description: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).value,
                value: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value
            };
        },
        getDOMstrings: function() {
            return DOMstrings;
        }
    };
})();

var controller = (function(budgetCtrl, UICtrl) {
    var setupEventListeners = function() {
        var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();

        document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener('click', ctrlAddItem);

        document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
                ctrlAddItem();
            }
        });
    };

    var ctrlAddItem = function() {
        var input, newItem;

        input = UICtrl.getInput();

        newItem = budgetCtrl.addItem(input.type, input.description, input.value);

        UICtrl.addListItem(newItem, input.type);
    };

    return {
        init: function() {
            setupEventListeners();
        }
    };
})(budgetController, UIController);

controller.init();
```

addListItem function won't work. I checked the budgetController function - nothing suspicious, nothing was wrong in there, yet I get the error in the console when I call it in the controller function saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: UICtrl.addListItem is not a function
>   at HTMLButtonElement.ctrlAddItem (app.js:108)

Comment: `addListItem` is defined in `budgetController`, not in `UIController`, so `UICtrl.addListItem` doesn't work

Comment: IT WORKS.
I can't believe I was so dumb to put it in a wrong place. Have a nice day, kind stranger!